# MQTT over websocket over Apache SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, proxy, mqtt

I have an mqtt broker providing unencrypted websocket. I would like to proxy it through an Apache which should encrypt the websocket to the outside.

It is an Apache 2.4 on a Windows machine.

My config is:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.someurl.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:9876/$1 [P,L]
  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.someurl.com
  
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache24/conf/ssl/some_certificate.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache24/conf/ssl/some_key.key"
  
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:9876/$1 [P,L]

  # Websocket proxy
  # wss redirects to working ws protocol
  # ProxyPass /wss ws://127.0.0.1:9876 retry=0 keepalive=On 
  # ProxyPassReverse /wss ws://127.0.0.1:9876 retry=0
 </VirtualHost>
```

I am able to connect through ws / port 80. It works fine. However, I am not able to connect using the wss.

I tried both using a rewriting and also a proxy_pass directives. I tried 100 different solution. However, this one looked most promising as port 80 is working for ws but not for the encrypted part. Any idea? Or I am just blinded by the options O:)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but as I've just got this working:

I have Mosquitto listening on port 8000 (which is firewalled to block any connections other than from localhost)

```
listener 8000
socket_domain ipv4
allow_anonymous true
protocol websockets
```

Then setup apache as so:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLCertificateFile ...
    SSLCertificateChainFile ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, the web-application is set to connect like so:

```js
mqtt.connect((window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:") + "//example.org/ws/");
```

Note that the proxy protocol can be "ws" or "wss" - both seem to work interchangeably. This is the connection between apache and mosquitto, there's no need to encrypt (they're on the same host). The use of the "/ws/" suffix on the path means I can do without mod_rewrite, and simply use mod_proxy.

This approach is the only way I could require authentication when accessed over HTTPS (which is public) but not over HTTP (which is behind the firewall).

Comment: while you say that the proxy is never wss, in the *:443 VirtualHost you ProxyPass to wss://localhost. Shouldn't it suffice to reverse-proxy to ws://localhost in all cases? Does Mosquitto even understant ws and wss on the same port?

Comment: Ugh, you're correct that paragraph doesn't match the example. You're correct that it doesn't actually matter - ws:// and wss:// both work the same way. Have updated the text.